# libdbus-java - CreateInterface fails with [Fatal Error] introspect.dtd:1:3:

Tags: java, dbus

I am looking to write some utility script with [groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/)  that make use of dbus. According to the documentation on [CreateInterface](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/dbus-java/dbus-javase10.html) the following command should generate a java source file for the approrpriate object.

```
CreateInterface --session  org.freedesktop.Notifications /org/freedesktop/Notifications
```

But no matter which interface I choose to attempt to generate the source file the command fails with

```
> [Fatal Error] introspect.dtd:1:3: The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//freedesktop//DTD D-BUS Object Introspection 1.0//EN; systemId: http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/introspect.dtd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 3; The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.bin.CreateInterface.createInterface(CreateInterface.java:702)
    at org.freedesktop.dbus.bin.CreateInterface.main(CreateInterface.java:685)
```

This happens on 16.04 and 16.10. I haven't tried other versions of Ubuntu. Anyone know if this utility is broken or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following:

```
gdbus introspect --session --dest org.freedesktop.Notifications --object-path /org/freedesktop/Notifications --xml | sed -e '/DOCTYPE/d' -e '/introspect.dtd/d' > org.freedesktop.Notifications.xml
CreateInterface --system --create-files org.freedesktop.Notifications.xml
```